Frobenius Theorem for Kernels
Given a $d$ dimensional manifold and $d$ vector fields $V_1, \cdots, V_d$, Frobenius' theorem states that if the commutator $[V_\alpha, V_\beta] = 0$ then there is a coordinate space for which the $V_\alpha = \partial_\alpha$ are base vectors.
Now assume that instead of the vector fields $V_\alpha$, we are given the kernel $K_{\alpha\beta}\equiv \langle V_\alpha, V_\beta\rangle$ as a field over the manifold. The question is: are there commuting vectors $V_\alpha$ that reproduce this kernel?
My progress: If $V_\alpha$ exists, then the metric tensor in the corresponding coordinate system will be the kernel $K_{\alpha\beta}$. So the question really becomes:
Is there a diffeomorphism from the coordinate-metric pair $(x^\mu, g_{\alpha\beta})$ to $(y^\mu, h_{\alpha\beta})$ such that $h_{\alpha\beta}(y(x)) = K_{\alpha\beta}(x)$.
Note that if we knew $h_{\alpha\beta}(y)$, then it would just be asking if these two manifolds are diffeomorphic, but we have the metric in one coordinate system as a function of the other coordinates.

This has nothing to do with metric tensors. Yes, if you have an integrable distribution, the Frobenius Theorem tells you that locally it is given by level sets of certain local coordinates.

@TedShifrin Well, in that coordinate system, the metric is $g_{\alpha\beta} = \langle \partial_\alpha, \partial_\beta\rangle$.

Why are you talking about metrics? Integrability of distributions and the Frobenius Theorem have nothing to do with Riemannian metrics.
